# OpenGL cube using a for loop

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl

Using C++ and OpenGL I have drawn a Cube using quads, lines and points. I am now trying to make my code denser. To achieve this I would like to use for loops.

My vertices for my cube are in a 2d array like this:

```
double vertices[8][3] = {
    { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, //0
    { 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f}, //1
    { 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f}, //2
    {-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f}, //3
    {-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f}, //4
    {-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f}, //5
    {-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f}, //6
    { 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f}  //7
};
```

Currently my code to draw the cube using lines is

```
void drawLines(){
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    //Front Lines
    //Left
    glVertex3f(vertices[5][0],vertices[5][1],vertices[5][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[4][0],vertices[4][1],vertices[4][2]);
    //Top
    glVertex3f(vertices[5][0],vertices[5][1],vertices[5][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[0][0],vertices[0][1],vertices[0][2]);
    //Bottom
    glVertex3f(vertices[4][0],vertices[4][1],vertices[4][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[7][0],vertices[7][1],vertices[7][2]);
    //Right
    glVertex3f(vertices[7][0],vertices[7][1],vertices[7][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[0][0],vertices[0][1],vertices[0][2]);
    //Middle Lines
    //Top Left
    glVertex3f(vertices[6][0],vertices[6][1],vertices[6][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[5][0],vertices[5][1],vertices[5][2]);
    //Top Right
    glVertex3f(vertices[1][0],vertices[1][1],vertices[1][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[0][0],vertices[0][1],vertices[0][2]);
    //Bottom Left
    glVertex3f(vertices[3][0],vertices[3][1],vertices[3][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[4][0],vertices[4][1],vertices[4][2]);
    //Bottom Right
    glVertex3f(vertices[2][0],vertices[2][1],vertices[2][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[7][0],vertices[7][1],vertices[7][2]);
    //Back Lines
    //Left
    glVertex3f(vertices[6][0],vertices[6][1],vertices[6][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[3][0],vertices[3][1],vertices[3][2]);
    //Top
    glVertex3f(vertices[6][0],vertices[6][1],vertices[6][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[1][0],vertices[1][1],vertices[1][2]);
    //Bottom
    glVertex3f(vertices[3][0],vertices[3][1],vertices[3][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[2][0],vertices[2][1],vertices[2][2]);
    //Right
    glVertex3f(vertices[2][0],vertices[2][1],vertices[2][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[1][0],vertices[1][1],vertices[1][2]);

    glEnd();                    // Done Drawing Edges
}
```

This achieves this result:
[image]

In an attempt to condense my code I am attempting to get the same result using for loops currently I have this:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);

for ( int i=0; i<8; i+=1 ) {
    for (int j=0; j<8; j+=1) {
        glVertex3f(vertices[i][0],vertices[i][1],vertices[i][2]);
        glVertex3f(vertices[j][0],vertices[j][1],vertices[j][2]);
    }
}
glEnd();
```

This gives me this result:
[image]

My question is, would anyone please be able to give me guidance to get the same result as I have with my original code?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to make an array of lines (vertex pairs) and iterate over it?

Comment: In your code, every vertex connects to every vertex (including itself). In a wireframe cube, every vertex connects to 3 other vertices. That cannot be done with a simple for-loop, it needs some additional guidance.

Comment: for the original result using for loop, check whether the vertecies are close enough before connecting to avoid the yucky diagonal lines.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add an array for the indices:

```
int[12][2] indices = {
    {5,4},
    {5,0},

    {4,7},
    {7,0},

    {6,5},
    {1,0},

    {3,4},
    {2,7},

    {6,3},
    {6,1},

    {3,2},
    {2,1}
}
```

and loop over that:

```
glBegin(GL_LINES);

for ( int i=0; i<12; i+=1 ) {

    glVertex3f(vertices[indices[i][0]][0],vertices[indices[i][0]][1],vertices[indices[i][0]][2]);
    glVertex3f(vertices[indices[i][1]][0],vertices[indices[i][1]][1],vertices[indices[i][1]][2]);
}
glEnd();
```

However using old (and deprecated) openGL like you are is not recommended for learning. Instead the suggested method is uploading the vertex data to a VBO; creating a set of shaders and use `glDrawArrays` or `glDrawElements` instead.